# class template for handling dynamic arrays of objects - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

I'm just getting started with the use of templates and class templates in university, and honestly it's getting a little confusing for me.

I have to create a Vector class (custom class not std::vector) that can take an array of objects and handle operations on that array, and also automatically increase the size of the array by *2 which you can see in my addData method in Vector. My Registration class creates an array of Vector (class) by taking inputs from a file, passing them into Results so that they read in the data from the file as required.

My Vector class is meant to set the data from Registration into results and increase the size of the array if needed. How would I have to make the input and output operators in my Vector class in order to do this, similarly to how I've done it for my Registration class as it uses file input?

Vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <class T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(int arraysize1): arraysize(arraysize1), data(new T[arraysize1]){};


Vector<T> *addData(T dataToAdd){

    Vector<T> *temp = new Vector<T> (this->arraysize);
    temp->data = this->data;
    Vector<T> *newData = new Vector<T> (this->arraysize*2);

    for (int x = 0; this->arraysize; x++){

        if(x < this->arraysize){

            newData->setData(temp->getData()[x],x);

        }
        else

            newData->setData(dataToAdd, x);

    }

    return newData;

};

void initArray(){

    for(int x = 0; x<this->arraysize; x++){

        this->setData(x ,x);

    }

};
void printArray(){
    std::ostringstream oss;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->arraysize; ++i){
        oss << this->data[i] + " ";
    }


};

T* getData(){

    return this->data;

};

int getSize(){

    return this->arraysize;

}

void setData(T data, int index){

    this->getData()[index] = data;

}
    private:
        int arraysize;
        T* data;

};


#endif // VECTOR_H
```

Registration.h(class that makes array of 'results' which is another class)
This is how my array of objects was declared before in my header file, and now I must use my vector class so I change the declaration:

```
Vector<Result> results;
```

Registration.cpp:

Here I use input stream and osteam operator overloading to read from the file. Now that Im using my vector class for Results, what syntax do I need to change?

```
void Registration::readFile(istream &input){

    long studentid1;
    unsigned semester1;


    input >> studentid1 >> semester1 >> count;

    input.ignore(100, '\n');


    SetStudentID(studentid1);
    SetSemester(semester1);


    for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    input >> results[i];

}

void Registration::writeFile(ostream & os) const{

    os << "Student ID: " << GetStudentID() << '\n'
     << "Semester:   " << GetSemester() << '\n';

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    os << results[i] << '\n';


}
```

If my Result class is needed and any other details do let me know.

Comment: Is the code you have working? If so, it's better to ask the question at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If it's not working, what is the observed problem? Can you shorten your code down to demonstrate the exact problem with a [mcve]?

Comment: I get this ` 
error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Vector<Result>' and 'unsigned int')| 
` 
at the line ` 
input >> results[i] 
`
in my readFile function in Registration. I've shortened my code and edited some stuff that I hope will help you understand

Comment: Basically I was reading in file input into an array of Results and sending it to Results to be read in the way I want it to using my methods. Now, I'm not sure how to read it into a Vector instead

Comment: You need to overload `operator[]` to use the subscript operator. And your `addItem` function is ... strange? `for (int x = 0; this->arraysize; x++)` is an endless loop, so you go out of of bounds in `newData->setData(dataToAdd, x);` sooner or later. Also your vector behaves more like an array. Is this really what it should do?

Comment: Second thing: `addItem` probably should not create a whole new instance with twice the size. Right now you would have to write `Vector<int> a; Vector<int> *afterAdd = a.addItem(0)`. Thereby having to delete the old instance after adding. Not to mention that you double the allocated size (actually you quadruple it, because the old memory is not freed and `temp` leaks) just by adding _one_ item. I think you should take a step back, get a clear understanding of what `addItem` is supposed to do and rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: @churill if i overload the subscript operator can it be used in my vector functions? And about the increasing array size, I'm not sure how to go about it otherwise. I am meant to increase it by *2 once the data in the array exceeds the size, can I do this by overloading the [] operator?

Comment: If you overload `operator[]` you can use it anywhere, yes. You already got the right concept, you need to increase the size of the array _when the number of elements exceeds the size_. This implies that you will need two variables. One for the size (number of elements contained) and capacity (number of allocated elements).